# Dictionary value always nil in swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
["Success": 1, "ControlId": <null>, "Message": Record has been saved, "MessageId": Record has been saved, "Source": <null>, "Result": 193, "ErrorCode": 0, "Description": <null>]
```

So I am doing like this

```
if let success=self.dm.responseDict["Success"] as? Int
{
    if (success==1)
    {
        callback(true)
    }
    else
    {
        if let errmsg=self.dm.responseDict["Message"] as? String
        {
            self.strErrorMessage=errmsg
        }
        callback(false)
    }
}
```

But my problem is this `success` is always nil and not satisfying the condition. Whats the reason for this and how can I  check this in correct way?

Comment: Perhaps the value for the "Success" key is a `Bool` instead of an `Int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `success` is `nil` then you have the error in your `as? Int` given that your dictionary looks like this:

```
["Success": 1, "ControlId": <null>, "Message": Record has been saved, "MessageId": Record has been saved, "Source": <null>, "Result": 193, "ErrorCode": 0, "Description": <null>]
```

So your `Success` value is probably a `Bool` instead of `Int`.

Try out this instead:

```
if let success = success=self.dm.responseDict["Success"] as? Bool {
    if success {
        callback(true)
    } else {
        if let errmsg=self.dm.responseDict["Message"] as? String {
            self.strErrorMessage=errmsg
        }
        callback(false)
    }
}
```